# Cosine similarity calculation

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

I am interested in calculating the cosine distance between each pair of the element of a sparse matrix. I am using the built-in function `DistanceMatrix` with the option `CosineDistance`.

My data is a sparse matrix `sp` with dimension `~{30000,6}` and number of non zero vectors in `sp` is ~3000. I calculate the distance matrix in the following manner:

```
sp = SparseArray[
  Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 30000}], RandomInteger[{1, 6}]} -> 
    RandomReal[1], {3000}]]

 DistanceMatrix[sp, 
    DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The calculation does not converge, any suggestion why the calculation does not converge.

I have a list of sparse matrices, and for each one of them, I want to calculate the cosine distance. I calculate the distance matrix with `@Henrik` solution.
When I run the code outside Module (or `Table` as in the following example), I get the distance matrix with right dimensions, but when I run it inside `Module`, I get wrong dimensions of the distance matrix.

```
SeedRandom[123];
sp = matrices[[1]];
ilist = Flatten[
   SparseArray[Unitize[Total[Abs[sp], {2}]]]["NonzeroPositions"]];
B = SparseArray[{}, {1, 1} Length[sp], 0.];
B[[ilist, ilist]] = 
    SparseArray@
     DistanceMatrix[sp[[ilist]], 
      DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

Table[
 sp = matrices[[i]];
 ilist = Flatten[
   SparseArray[Unitize[Total[Abs[sp], {2}]]]["NonzeroPositions"]];
 BB = SparseArray[{}, {1, 1} Length[sp], 0.];
 BB[[ilist, ilist]] = 
  SparseArray@
   DistanceMatrix[sp[[ilist]], 
    DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance], {i, 1}]
```

Comment: Please provide all necessary code to reproduce your problem, especially if you're asking why a specific example does not behave as expected. Otherwise, it is very hard or even impossible to help you

Comment: Please see an example, I added a sparse matrix.

Comment: Try this: `Table[sp = matrices[[i]];
 ilist = Flatten[
   SparseArray[Unitize[Total[Abs[sp], {2}]]]["NonzeroPositions"]];
 BB = SparseArray[{}, {1, 1} Length[sp], 0.];
 BB[[ilist, ilist]] = 
  SparseArray@
   DistanceMatrix[sp[[ilist]], DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance];
 BB,
 {i, 1}
 ]`. The return value should be `BB`. But the return value of `BB[[ilist, ilist]] =  ...`  is only the submatrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following. It computes the distance matrix of merely the nonzero rows.

```
SeedRandom[123];
sp = SparseArray[ Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 30000}], RandomInteger[{1, 6}]} -> RandomReal[1], {3000}]];
ilist = Flatten[SparseArray[Unitize[Total[Abs[sp], {2}]]]["NonzeroPositions"]];
A = SparseArray[{}, {1, 1} Length[sp], 0.];
A[[ilist, ilist]] = SparseArray@DistanceMatrix[
 sp[[ilist]], 
 DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance
 ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.384662

Comment: Thank you @Henrik

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I would need the code in order to say anything about it.

Comment: I  edited the question